# Who is this Greek goddess?

Tags: greek

[image: Close up of what she is holding]Please help me identify this Greek goddess statue in the attached image. Who is this? She is wearing a hat of some kind and is holding flowers or some other plants.

[image: Greek goddess]

Comment: It would be helpful to know, which flowers/plants she is holding. Can you describe them in more detail?

Comment: Hi, user5575. Can you tell us more information about the photograph, like where it was taken?

Comment: It was in a flea market

Answer (score 4):

Reminds me of a [Kore (sculpture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kore_(sculpture)) and the plants look like they might be [poppy bulbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opium), which are associated with [the Kore (aka Persephone)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persephone), and her mother [Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demeter#Agricultural_deity).

Comment: Her hat, too, could be a polos, which Demeter and [Persephone](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bb/70/55/bb7055b0f4ba479defb5ed352d5ef257.jpg) both wore. (See [this link](http://www.rwaag.org/polos), which illustrates the various poloi with Barbie dolls.)

Answer (score -1):

Demeter cause of all the plants she was the Goddess of the harvest

Comment: Isn't Demeter rather depicted with grain than with flowers?